# Update date sting in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table:

```
id | time
--------------------
1  | 12.09.2022 13:01
2  | 12.09.2022 13:02
3  | 12.09.2022 13:03
4  | 12.09.2022 13:04
```

The `time` column is of type `VARCHAR`.

I need to convert from `12.09.2022 13:01` to `2022-9-12 13:01`

Can I do this with SQL like `UPDATE` query?

PostgreSQL

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle, MSSQL etc.,?

Comment: ... also, you'd be better off if you changed the column to an appropriate date/time type.

Comment: @Arun Palanisamy PostgreSQL

Comment: just cast the "TIME" column into datetime with FORMAT to DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue once and for all, change the datatype:

```
ALTER TABLE foo
    ALTER COLUMN time SET data type TIMESTAMP USING(to_timestamp(time, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'))
```

to_timestamp(time, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') will convert the varchar to a proper timestamp.

And of course you should also fix your input, somebody did a nasty INSERT on this table...